# MDX query to write YOY Calculation In Excel

Tags: excel, mdx

My excel is connected to a cube. I want to create a Measure in Excel itself, to calculate YOY so that I can drag that into the value section of Pivot table.

Sample Data (Pivot table that is connected to Model)

- Date[MonthYear]
- Product[ProductName]
- Sales[TotalAmount]

I want to calculate YOY % calculation:

```
(2022-12 Sales - 2021-12 Sales ) / (2021-12 Sales)
```

Above calculation I need to build directly in Excel using the OLAP tool.

I am unable to get `MDX` logic so that it works in Excel. Need help to get the calculation works in Excel

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your Date dimension look like? Are you able to post a picture of the user and attribute hierarchies available in that dimension?

Answer (score 1):

We don't know enough about your cube structure to give a definite answer to the question.

To find the amount for the equivalent month in the previous year you would generally use the `PARALLELPERIOD` function (the following is inside a tuple with the target measure)

```
(
  ParallelPeriod([Dare].[Date].[Year],1,[Date].[Date].currentmember)
  ,[Measures].[TotalAmount]
)
```

Current value would be this:

```
( [Date].[Date].currentmember ,[Measures].[TotalAmount] )
```

So your calculation would be:

```
(
 ( [Date].[Date].currentmember ,[Measures].[TotalAmount] )
 - 
 (
  ParallelPeriod([Dare].[Date].[Year],1,[Date].[Date].currentmember)
  ,[Measures].[TotalAmount]
 )
)
/
(
  ParallelPeriod([Dare].[Date].[Year],1,[Date].[Date].currentmember)
  ,[Measures].[TotalAmount]
)
```